# Updating an active Designer workflow

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

In SP2010, I have a list workflow that was built in Designer only - no code. I need to make a small change and must understand what happens to workflows in progress when I do this. The workflow assigns tasks to various users and I need to change who one of the tasks gets assigned to. It's fine if the workflows already in progress don't see the change, since the task has already been assigned for those users (but possibly not completed yet). I just want new workflows to assign the tasks to the appropriate users as they start up.

If I make the change in Designer and save and publish, will the two versions of the workflow running at the same time automatically be managed correctly? or am I going to break the active workflows by making a change?

Answer (score 2):

Running workflows will use the old model, new workflows (the ones started after you published changes) will use the new one.